# Simple Friend System Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

guys I just want to ask how to make a simple friend system? I already make a table for the friend list and request and i can already add friend but my problem is there is only one account i can add. How could i solve it? If somebody knows please tell me.

Comment: make a user table with username and password for different users..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you just need a table of users and then a join table called something like users_to_friends where you store the user_id and the user_id of their friend